# Deploying AngularJS 1.x - Webpack app to Tomcat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat, spring-boot, webpack

I've searched all over google and checked out the official docs for Webpack but have not had any luck finding a tutorial/guide/plugin to even do this.  Has anyone done this before or should I just drop webpack altogether and go for a grunt-maven-war file generator instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing special in building spring-boot with webpack. You can install node globally, you can install it during build...
You just add plugin to pom.xml to run node command i.e. (https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)

And that actually it. It runs webpack and you get your js, css, fonts, ... files in some folder. Now you proceed like it is usual static assets, pack them into war and enjoy.